# Watch angular service methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm geting into angular and i have the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne5P8/679/)

html

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <p>{{val}}</p>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('testService', function(){
    var myVal = new Date();

    this.val = function(){
        return myVal;
    };

    setInterval(function () { myVal = new Date(); console.log(myVal);}, 3000);
});

function Ctrl($scope, testService)
{
    $scope.testService = testService;
    $scope.val = testService.val();
    $scope.$watch('testService.val()', function (newVal) {
        $scope.val = newVal;        
    });

}
```

but even if the setInterval is being executed it does not trigger the Ctrl watch statement

what am i missing?

Edit: i think some answers focused on the setInterval function when it was the simplest mechanism that came to my mind to change the myVal property. In my real app this values being changed by a fabric JS (canvas library) event.

How can i say to angular to run a digest cicle (because this property thats suposed to be watched changed its value) without manually call apply (which is causing me some errors as "an apply is already in process" or something

I tried to simplify my issue wich a demo but i'm sorry if  wasn't clear

Answer (score 0):

Not that I fully understand AngularJS, but I believe that `setInterval` doesn't cause Angular to run a digest cycle, which causes the `$watch` to see changes. Using `$timeout`, you can get what you desire. Here's an example of how I'd set up your service:

```
app.service('testService', function ($timeout) {
    var myVal = new Date();

    this.val = function(){
        return myVal;
    };

    updateVal();

    function updateVal() {
        myVal = new Date();
        console.log(myVal);
        $timeout(updateVal, 1000);
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LuNqX/

The demo has a shorter timeout, to see the changes better.

Also, I updated the Controller because it seemed weird how the service was being used.

---

**References:**

- `$timeout` - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout

Answer (score -1):

$watch is looking at the scope. You asked it to watch $scope['testService.val()'] which does not work. You can use a function as the first param and return that value.

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return testService.val(); } , function (newVal) {
    $scope.val = newVal;        
});
```

Comment: While I agree this is how I think it should be done (like in my answer), this isn't the problem. The way the OP had it should work, but I think it's weird/unnecessary. Here's the OP's way of `$watch`ing working: http://jsfiddle.net/p76Hn/ . I think this only works because the OP does `$scope.testService = testService;` which seems crazy to me

Comment: Newer versions have $interval too, if you really want to do it the way the OP posted.

Comment: I notice that the quoted value worked becuase i set it on a scope property (that was the example i used because it was my last try). But i think the answers went on the wrong direction because they focused on the setInterval function which was the simplestway that came to my mind to me of changing the value of the service property myVal.